# Preloader is not hidden even after page loaded on mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, preloader

I have a very annoying issue with jquery. I have included a preloader on my project and it works great as it should on desktop. However, on mobile preloader is not hidden after page loaded.

**Note:** It works only on first page load. On the next tries, when page is loaded from cache, it does not.

I have tried native javascript code also. Tried .bind(), .load() and etc. Nothing works.

```
// Global Variables
    var $W = $(window),
        $D = $(document),
        $B = $('body'),
        $header = $('#header'),
        $preloader = $('#preloader');

    // Page Load
    $W.on('load', function () {

        // Hide Preloader on Page Load
        $preloader.fadeOut('fast');

        // Init Particles on Page Load
        if ($W.width() > 1024) {
            var particlesContainer = $('#particles');
            if (particlesContainer.length > 0) {
                particlesJS.load('particles', 'assets/js/particles.json', function () {
                    // console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Actual test site URL: https://www.3031313.xyz/

Responsiveness is not optimized yet.

Comment: I don't see the issue in FF or Chrome running in responsive web view.  The loader goes away in both cases, even after repeated refreshing.  EDIT: I do see it in my android chrome though.

Comment: The problem is only on mobile browsers.

Comment: So let me ask this, what are you waiting to load, before you script executes?

Comment: Images on the page. Mainly on the landing panel which is always seen first. Edit: Images are not optimized yet.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I feel like the potential issue here is that the binding on the load event is happening inside a document ready.  And a load event is not always guarenteed to happen after the ready.

Comment: Yes, it is in document ready. That can be the issue. I will try it outside the ready. But why? On other projects of mine it works great even in ready function.

Comment: Dunno, like I said.  The order is not always guarenteed and I would think when resources are cached already, that the load and ready could happen almost simultaneously, which would make binding for a *future* load event not work.

Comment: I noticed that it does not work when content is cached. So seems to be you are right. But how writing the load function out of the ready can help?

Comment: If the load binding is not in the ready, it will be created at the time that the script is being processed, which is before the load event happens.

Comment: Yes, here is the logic. Ok, then i will try as soon as i get to my notebook. Anyway, thanks for proposing an idea.